# Jmeter Regular expression extractor not getting result in Listener

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am using Regular expression for pattern -  and `<em>(.+?)</em>` for the password

But after running Jmeter I am getting request like below in View result tree Listner -

```
password=%7BUserid_g1%7D
```

Value of password is not storing after applying regular expression.

I have also set the variable as - `{Userid_g2)` in password field.

tell me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

> {Userid_g2)

by :

> ${Userid}

_g2 suffix indicates the capturing group of your regexp, can you show it ? there might also be an error there

Comment: Hi, tried with above syntax also but still getting same issue